# What is the cheapest Amazon S3 account you buy for simple image hosting?

Tags: hosting, amazon-s3

Exactly as the title goes, what is the cheapest Amazon S3 account you can buy for simple image hosting?

I've been reviewing their pricing charts [here](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing), but I can't make any sense of it. Any veterans out there care to spare an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you're interested in S3, you should look at the S3 pricing charts here: http://aws.amazon.com/s3/#pricing -- your link goes to EC2, which is not the same product.

Comment: That was exactly the answer to my question! Thanks!